# Verificar se horario de funcionamento está no range de tempo escolhido JQuery/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como verificar se o horario_funcionamento esta dentro do range de intervalo_escolhido? Exemplo: um bar funciona das 08:00 as 13:00, um usuario escolheu o intervalo de tempo das 12:00 as 21:00, como verificar se esse bar está aberto nesse range de tempo escolhido?

```
var intervalo_escolhido = [12,21];
var horario_funcionamento = [08,13];
```

Comment: Preciso realizar o teste com os 2 valores do horario de funcionamento.

Comment: É a mesma pergunta que a anterior, simplesmente tem que usar a solução apresentada duas vezes.

Comment: Ou utilizar um for ou foreach para caso o vetor horarios funcionamento tenha um tamanho variável

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
verificaHorario(7, 16);

function verificaHorario(horario_inicial, horario_final) {
  var horario_funcionamento = [08, 13];
  for (var horario = horario_inicial; horario <= horario_final; horario++) {
    if (horario < horario_funcionamento[0] || horario >= horario_funcionamento[1]) {
      alert("Horario indisponivel dentro do intervalo escolhido: " + horario);
    } else {
      alert("Horario disponivel dentro do intervalo escolhido: " + horario);
    }
  }
}
```

Espero ter entendido a pergunta e ter ajudado. Caso não seja isso, me informe que tento novamente te ajudar.

Comment: Nesse exemplo que voce passou era para exibir que esta dentro do horario de funcionamento, ex: ele funciona das 08:00 as 13:00 e voce passou o intervalo de 07:00 as 12:00...em um determinado momento era para estar em horario de funcionamento.

Comment: Ah sim,você quer verificar durante todo o range. Da uma olhada na resposta agora, pois está mostrando os horários disponíveis e indisponíveis dentro do range escolhido. Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando esses dados que você colocou você pode verificar pelo índice dos arrays:

```
function VerificaRange(range){
  var horario_funcionamento = [08,13];
  if (range[0] >= horario_funcionamento[0] && range[1] <= horario_funcionamento[1]){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }      
}

var intervalo_escolhido = [12,21];
//return false;
var insideRange = VerificaRAnge(intervalo_escolhido);
```